# Is there a way to log with logback in a basic spring-boot java app using another user maybe with jcifs?

Tags: java, logback, jcifs

Is there any logback extension or module or any way that supports logging with a different user than the  app starting user?
I am using basic spring-boot java app on windows. No web.

I've tried to override logback inner classes, but it's a bit way too complicated, because itt needs a couple of java classes to be overidden.

Comment: What do you mean by "logging with a different user"?

Comment: As I was asking in the question: a different user (authenticated by username/pass with jcifs) than the app starting user. This means that when I start the java app using user A, but the log dir has write permission only for user B.